# add dependency on cmake's built-in target

Tags: c, cmake

Let's suppose we want to build a simple library, with one header file and one source file (**my_lib.c** and **my_lib.h**, respectively).
The CMakeLists.txt will be something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(example C)
add_library(example my_lib.c my_lib.h)
```

the available targets are (output from `make help`):

- **my_lib.i**
- ...

Now, suppose we have a script (let's say **my_script.py**) that requires the preprocessed output of **my_lib.c** (the output of target **my_lib.i**) as an input parameter.
So, we add the following code to our CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_target(my_script
    DEPENDS 
    COMMAND python my_scipt.py path/to/my_lib.i)
```

The question is: is it possible to add a dependency (`DEPENDS` parameter of `add_custom_target` above) in order to build target **my_lib.i**?

I have read similar questions, but all propose to invoke the preprocessor explicitly, which will probably break the build by modifying the compiler.

Thanks

Comment: This cannot be done in the general case, because whether such "targets for individual steps" exist or not depends on the generator: e.g. the Visual Studio generator does not contain any such "targets".

Comment: That's what `add_dependency` is for.  Your custom target depends on the completion of of the target `example`.  When building `example` you need to make sure that compiling `my_lib.c` generates the file `my_lib.i`. The `add_custom_target` `DEPENDS` wouldn't trigger `my_lib.i` to get built. Alternatively you could add a custom command to run `make my_lib.i` to generate the file.